# How to globally disable and re-enable Echo?

Tags: debugging

I have Echo's buried in code all over my notebook, I'd like a flag to turn them all on or off globally.

- Sure `Unprotect[Echo];Echo=Identity` would disable them, but then you can't re-enable them
- A solution that works for all the various types of Echos (EchoName, EchoEvaluation, ...) would be nice
- `QuietEcho` doesn't work because I'd have to write it add it around every blob of code

Comment: with `Echo=.`, no?

Comment: sure, but how do reenable it without restarting the kernel

Comment: Mmm, maybe I did not understand the question, but `Unprotect[Echo]; Echo =Identity;Do[Echo@i, {i, 10}];(*whatever code you want to be muted*)` and later `Echo =.;Do[Echo@i, {i, 10}]` does not do the trick?

Comment: No that won't work, nothing is echoed, don't you see?

Comment: Sorry, I do now. Hmm, looks like a bug.

Comment: Use `OwnValues[Echo] = {}` instead.

Comment: Also, you might use `Echo = #&` instead, since `Echo` can take multiple arguments.

Comment: I would advocate for a global search-and-replace of all `Echo[` with `myEcho` in your code, then at the top assign an appropriate value to `myEcho`, i.e. `myEcho = Echo` vs. `myEcho = Identity` depending on what you want. The global search should be relatively safe and painless, since `Echo` is not a common keyword in other function names. This would also work with all other `types of Echo`, turning them into `myEcho...` versions if you wanted.

Comment: Wow, I just found that if you echo something prior to muting, then you can turn echo on as I and/or @CarlWoll suggested. E.g.,  `Echo[0];Unprotect[Echo]; Echo =Identity;Do[Echo@i, {i, 10}];(*whatever code you want to be muted*)` and later `Echo =.;Do[Echo@i, {i, 10}]` does work. But if you omit `Echo[0]`, echo can not be turned on neither with `Echo=.` nor with `OwnValues[Echo]={}`

Comment: @RomaLee This is likely due to `Echo` being one of the autoloaded symbols. Check, e.g. on a fresh kernel, this: `OwnValues[Echo]`, you will see something like ``{HoldPattern[Echo] :>  System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[Echo], Hold[Echo, EchoFunction], "Language`Echo`"] /; System`Dump`TestLoad}``. So, initially, `Echo` has `OwnValues`. When you execute `Echo[0]` (actually, just `Echo` is enough), you cause that definition to run. As a result, `OwnValues[Echo]` get cleared, instead `DownValues[Echo]` get populated.  When you do `Echo = Identity` without auto-load, you hopelessly overwrite autoload code.

Comment: @RomaLee Ok, Carl mentioned the same thing just now in his answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo) has an autoload, so you need to make sure the symbol is autoloaded before you modify its values:

```
DisableEcho[] := (Unprotect[Echo]; Echo; Echo = #&; Protect[Echo];)

EnableEcho[] := (Unprotect[Echo]; Echo=.; Protect[Echo];)
```

Test:

```
DisableEcho[]

Echo[3]

EnableEcho[]

Echo[3, "EchoLabel"]
```

> 3

> EchoLabel 3

> 3

Comment: Ah, I forgot the autoload

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `QuietEcho` rather than redefining `Echo`:

```
In[62]:= $Pre = QuietEcho;

In[63]:= Echo[3]

Out[63]= 3
```

This has the added benefit of disabling printing for all `Echo` functions, not just `Echo`.